# How to add windows exporter to Prometheus server in Kubernetes(AKS)?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, monitoring, azure-aks, metrics

I have deployed an AKS cluster with 2 node pools i.e. windows and linux. I am trying to add a monitoring solution to it with promethues and grafana. I am using node exporter for linux node metrics and windows exporter (wmi exporter) for windows node metrics. All the workloads are up and running. I can see the metrics by doing port forwarding on both linux and windows node.
The problem is while integrating it with prometheus node exporter is showing me up and running but windows exporter is down.
[image: prometheus]

The entry which I made in prometheus.yml for both is

```
      - job_name: 'win-exporter'
        kubernetes_sd_configs:
          - role: endpoints
        relabel_configs:
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_endpoints_name]
          regex: 'win-node-exporter'
          action: keep

      - job_name: 'node-exporter'
        kubernetes_sd_configs:
          - role: endpoints
        relabel_configs:
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_endpoints_name]
          regex: 'node-exporter'
          action: keep
```

regex represent the endpoint names. I don't know why it is not working there. Both node exporter and windows exporter are daemonset.
workload running are
[image: Service and endpoints]

Can anyone help for how to make the windows exporter entry in prometheus.yml file.
Thank you in advance.